# What is the purpose of the Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange Instagram account?

Tags: discussion, social-networking, instagram

The [recent blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/27/stack-overflow-instagram-account/) indicates that it is for "highlighting blog posts, podcast episodes, The Overflow newsletter, community announcements, company news, and product updates." However, I don't understand the value in this Instagram account as it currently exists.

Specifically:

- Someone is either buying or designing graphics for each post. However, there are now many graduated (non Beta) sites that don't have designs yet. Why is time and/or money being invested in an Instagram account when successfully launched communities have a bland, non-unique design?
- One could argue that it's much like the various Twitter accounts. However, why are the links to the relevant content not in the posts being shared? Most of them refer to the bio. This makes it difficult or impossible for sharing via Instagram.
- How are posts selected? Are communities consulted to ensure that the shared questions are appropriate and reflective of the community? Sharing popular but otherwise lower quality questions has a chance to do a disservice to the community that is being linked to. It seems like anyone can submit a question for consideration, but there's no clear vetting process.

I'm not opposed to social media accounts that, among other things, highlight interesting and relevant questions across the network. However, there should be some transparency regarding how it works and making sure that the effort expended is adding value.

Comment: I feel like I'd love to see this expanded into "what's SEI's general communications strategy (esp. wrt blog, twitter, now IG, podcast, &c.)?" I don't know if that's an interest to you, though....

Comment: @nitsua60 I think that's a good question, but probably separate from this one.

Comment: It appears to have been created because someone said "*We should have an Instagram channel, everyone has an Instagram channel these days*" and then pointed at [someone in the meeting who wasn't quick enough to come up with an excuse for them not to be responsible for it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0j8M4hlXcw)

Comment: @ThomasOwens fair. If I ever make it through my current Zoom-gauntlet, I may post it....

Comment: Re: `However, why are the links to the relevant content not in the posts being shared? Most of them refer to the bio` - that's because Instagram doesn't allow you to put clickable links in the text that accompanies posts, "link in bio" with the link going to a landing page, is a fairly common thing

Answer (score 16):

First a non-answer part:

> However, there should be some transparency regarding how it works and making sure that the effort expended is adding value.

Well, that is up to the company. As long as their instagram account isn't used to drive discussions shaping the future of community-relevant topics, why should we care much?

Sure: it would be nice to know what their strategy is. But in the end, it is their business. Meaning: all the "social media" accounts are clearly on "their turf", and therefore it is "their" decision what they do, and how they do it, and what they tell us about it.

Obviously, they shouldn't repeat past mistakes, and consider a random response on such channels to be a "game changing event", that pushes actions that were ignored for months when requested by the communities.

Beyond that:

> However, I don't understand the value in this Instagram account as it currently exists.

That account exists to create attention and attract viewers. I think Yaakov mentioned somewhere that the traffic increased by a factor of 4 since the stackoverflow blog was revived, and keeps pushing out content that many people find interesting.

And the simple reality is: Instagram *is* a platform that becomes more and more relevant. Yes, personally, I find their current posts to be a bit confusing, and it took me a while to figure what "link in bio" means. But supposedly, these days, when you are in this segment of IT, not having an Instagram account accounts for a big minus.

> Are communities consulted to ensure that the shared questions are appropriate and reflective of the community?

Interesting idea, but not realistic, imho:

- They do have the right to promote content as they wish, as long as they do not violate the licence
- They promote content to push their business, not "the communities".

Long story short:

- Yes, out of curiosity, me, too ... I hope that a company official adds an answer here and gives some further thoughts.
- But, as said: to a certain degree, this isn't *our* business. If they want to share their thoughts (and maybe ask for helpful feedback): fine with me. If not, nothing to worry about. I care much more about their continuation of their road map for working with the communities and moderators. That is **our** turf, that is where I want them to focus, too (regarding company/community interaction priorities).

Comment: I know it's grammatically correct, but seeing "account accounts" there makes me deeply uncomfortable...

Comment: Luckily for me, there is no flag for posts that do mind boggling language bending. So sorry, that's just me. I guess I subconsciously picked that wording to express the fact ... that, me personally ... don't get that hype about Instagram. Actually, i kinda hate it.